# Column Wordwrap in JQGrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, word-wrap

Anybody knows on how to wrap column names in JQGrid. Please find my JSON code below

colModel: [
            { name: 'RequestID', index: 'CreditRequest.CreditRequestID', width:100, align: 'left' },.....

With reference to the above code if the size of the content exceeds I want it to be wrapped. Any thoughts or comments

Comment: So you want to wrap the column header name? Are you expecting this to change dynamically or do you just have really long names?  It may help for you to post more information...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well the simplest way to ensure a line break is to put a `<BR/>` tag in the column name where ever you need a line break. For instance `ClientPrimaryName` can be written as `Client<BR/>PrimaryName`, so that it actually renders as:

Client
PrimaryName

Comment: add a line break but still doesn't expand the cell vertically.

Answer (score 14):

Just reference it in your own css file.

```
.ui-jqgrid tr.jqgrow td {
    height: 50px;
    white-space: normal;
}
```

As long as your css file is listed in the header after the jqGrid.css file then it will override it.

Answer (score 8):

For what it's worth, here it is for the header row:

```
.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-htable th div, .ui-jqgrid-sortable  {
    height:auto;
    overflow:hidden;
    white-space:normal !important;
}
```

Comment: Best solution on the page

Answer (score 4):

You need to take a look at the specific classes applied to your jqGrid th column headers. In my case I had the following: `ui-th-div-ie ui-jqgrid-sortable`

Looking a little further I found that there were two CSS issues:

1. white-space: normal
2. height: 16px

Both these CSS attributes where defined in ui.jqgrid.css. Realising that I had a specific requirement for this grid that I didnt want to have affecting other implementations I came up with the following solution:

```
$(".ui-jqgrid-sortable").css('white-space', 'normal');
$(".ui-jqgrid-sortable").css('height', 'auto');
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is a few steps to enable word  wrapping in the cells.

Open up ui.jqgrid.css
Search for .ui-jqgrid tr.jqgrow td
Change “white-space: pre;” to   “white-space: normal;”

For wrap in cell:

```
.ui-jqgrid tr.jqgrow td {
    white-space: normal !important;
    height:auto;
    vertical-align:text-top;
    padding-top:2px;
}
```

And for column headers

```
.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-htable th div {
        height:auto;
    overflow:hidden;
    padding-right:4px;
    padding-top:2px;
    position:relative;
    vertical-align:text-top;
    white-space:normal !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set a white-space css property of th tag to normal.  Using JQuery that should be:

```
  $('.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-htable th div').css('white-space', 'normal');
```

Comment: Hi,
This is not working for me. Any other suggestions? I need it very badly.

Answer (score 0):

Use this css

```
   .ui-jqgrid tr.jqgrow td {
        word-wrap: break-word; /* IE 5.5+ and CSS3 */
        white-space: pre-wrap; /* CSS3 */
        white-space: -moz-pre-wrap; /* Mozilla, since 1999 */
        white-space: -pre-wrap; /* Opera 4-6 */
        white-space: -o-pre-wrap; /* Opera 7 */
        overflow: hidden;
        height: auto;
        vertical-align: middle;
        padding-top: 3px;
        padding-bottom: 3px
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you cant just put a `<BR/>` , while that works on wrapping the line - it doesnt adjust the height properly

Answer (score 0):

This worked with jqGrid  4.4.4

```
.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-htable th div
{
    white-space:normal;
    height:auto !important;
}
```