# jqGrid navigator view text word-wrap

Tags: jquery, struts2, jqgrid, struts2-jquery

So I have a navigator view in my Struts jqGrid that I am using to just display information about the columns in the selected row. I have a column that holds the information for a comments textarea that can have too much information to be shown in the grid at any one time. I would like to use the navigator view to see the text in this column as a word-wrapped paragraph however there is no formatting options that I can find. Currently the text is in a single line and the user must use the horizontal scroll-bar to scroll through the text. Unfortunately the documentation is poor but I would assume that there would be an option that I can add to this line in my jqGrid:

```
navigatorViewOptions="{width:600,reloadAfterSubmit:false}"
```

Or have something similar to my editoptions on my gridColumn itself:

```
 <sjg:gridColumn name="asiNotes" edittype="textarea" editoptions="{ maxlength: 500, rows:3,cols:70 }"/>
```

I have also tried `$("#v_asiNotes").wrap` on the id in the view that needs to be word-wrapped with no avail.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried changing CSS? Like in this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3161326/2571926) or in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6915486/2571926)?

Comment: You can also override the theme the plugin used by default.

Comment: Yea sounds like I am going to have to look into that.

Comment: @IlyaLuzyanin, that is the right answer. Also, when you are using jqGrid and there is an answer by Oleg, that's the right answer too :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved it by using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8170090/jqgrid-viewgridrow-dialog-big-span-and-icon/8171924#8171924) solution by Oleg. I had to edit the CSS for the dialog window itself with this style:

```
div.ui-jqdialog-content td.form-view-data {
    white-space: normal !important;
    height: auto;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding-top: 3px; padding-bottom: 3px
}
```